# Span in table tr on the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table, and i want to locate a color span in the right of every row. but when i try that, i'm founding my span on the top of the table.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredTenders">
    <tr class="clickable">
        <span class="row-indicator"></span>
        <td>{{endsIn}}</td>
        <td >{{amount | number}}</td>
        <td>{{currencies}}</td>
        <td>{{createdIn()}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `<span>` as a child of table row (`<tr>`). `to the right of every row` as I understand it, means last cell in the row? If so, try this:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredTenders">
     <tr class="clickable">
         <td>{{endsIn}}</td>
         <td >{{amount | number}}</td>
         <td>{{currencies}}</td>
         <td>{{createdIn()}}</td>
         <td><span class="row-indicator"></span></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only put `<td>` elements inside a `<tr>`. If you want to have an element at the right of every row, you'll have to put it in the last `<td>` of that `<tr>`.